# how i can converti string arabica to date format English Wit flutter frome الثلاثاء 01 يونيو 2021 to 01/05/2021

Tags: android, flutter, date, dart, mobile

from

```
الثلاثاء 01 يونيو 2021
```

to

```
01/05/2021
```

how i can convert string arabic to date format English with flutter from الثلاثاء 01 يونيو 2021 to 01/05/2021 jj/mm/yyyy dart language form string to

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION

```
static int checkarabicdate(Date) {
    String mm ="";

    String dt = Date.substring(Date.indexOf(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),Date.length-1);
    print(dt);
    var currentDate = DateTime.now();

    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(currentDate);

    DateTime date1 = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(formattedDate);
    print(date1);


    List<String> validadeSplit = dt.split(' ');

    String day = validadeSplit[0].toString();
    print(day);
    String month = validadeSplit[1].toString();
    print(month);
    String year = validadeSplit[2].toString();
    print(year);

    //   var  parsedDate = DateTime.parse('$year-$month-$day 00:00:00.000');

      if(month=="يناير") {
        mm = "01";
      }
      else if(month=="فبراير") {
        mm = "02";
      }
      else if(month=="مارس") {
        mm = "03";
      }

      else if(month=="أبريل") {
        mm = "04";
      }

      else if(month=="مايو") {
        mm = "05";
      }
      else if(month=="يونيو") {
        mm = "06";
      }
      else if(month=="يوليو") {
        mm = "07";
      }
      else if(month=="أغسطس") {
        mm = "08";
      }
      else if(month=="سبتمبر") {
        mm = "09";
      }
      else if(month=="أكتوبر") {
        mm = "10";
      }
      else if(month=="نوفمبر") {
        mm = "11";
      }
      else if(month=="ديسمبر") {
        mm = "12";
      }
      else mm ="01";

 
    DateTime start = DateTime.parse('$year-$mm-$day'.replaceAll(' ', ''));
    
    print(start);
    // DateTime date2= new   DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(date);
    //print(parsedDate);
    date1 = DateTime(date1.year, date1.month, date1.day);
    start = DateTime(start.year, start.month, start.day);
    final differenceInDays = (date1.difference(start).inHours / 24).round();
    print('$differenceInDays');

    return differenceInDays;
  }
```